# How to force webpack to load an undetected dependency from the standpoint of a library author?

Tags: javascript, webpack, dependency-injection, node-modules, polyfills

Let's say I have a module `foo` which has a polyfill `bar` as a dependency.

- `foo` and `bar` are npm modules
- the polyfill provides the upcoming `Array.lol` and hence **doesn't return anything**
- the module assumes `Array.lol` exists and **doesn't require/import `bar`**
- `foo`'s package.json has `bar` as a dependency
- the user shouldn't have to do more than `import qux from 'foo'`

How do I force webpack to load `bar`?

Comment: You can't. Webpack has to know all the dependencies EXPLICITLY!

Comment: @PlayMa256 can't I use the [browser field](https://github.com/defunctzombie/package-browser-field-spec) to circumvent `main`? e.g. `"bar": true`

Answer (score 0):

if the foo package has bar as a dependency but is not requiring or importing it, there's no way that can be visible in the global scope, if foo asumes the package bar being loaded in a script tag, you should import it before importing the foo package.

```
import bar from 'bar'
import foo from 'foo' // After bar has been imported.
```